# Downloading a CSV file from a dynamic webpage in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests, urllib

A CSV file is periodically uploaded to a known, constant URL (url_variable).  I want to automatically download the latest iteration of that CSV file in the course of a Python script.

I have tried using Pandas, specifically pd.read_csv(url_variable), but I receive the "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden."

Next I tried using urllib and passing in spoofed headers (headers_variable), specifically urllib.requests.Request(url_variable, headers=headers_variable).  This technique works.  However, when a new CSV file is uploaded to the URL and the script is repeated, the old CSV file is returned.

How can I alter my code to download the new CSV file each time this block is called?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if url is the same for new CSV uploads. If it's the same just downloading it should work.

Here's an example of downloading a CSV file in memory and reading it directly using requests and pandas:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import requests
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
        
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv'
    headers = {"Authorization": "Test"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text))
    print(df.shape)
```

Of course, adjust headers as you wish.
If the file is large, you could use a temporary file in order to process it, see: [Generate temporary files and directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  This code works as advertised.

However, the problem persists.  When I update the .csv file and call the code again, I receive the former .csv file, not the updated one.  At this point, I believe the issue is with the security settings of the webhost, whereas before I thought the issue was in the session or headers passed from the Python code to the site.

Comment: You're welcome. Yea, look at the server side, if the file is updated the server should give you the latest version unless the new file has a new url.

Comment: Thanks, I set the server to cache nothing, and it seems to have fixed the issue!

Comment: @BigDBot Nice! I'm glad you made it work. Cheers!